# Using the WebForms ReportViewer 10.0 with a Reporting Services 2012 instance

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, reportviewer2008

Does anyone know definitively whether the ReportViewer 10.0 webforms control works correctly against a Reporting Services 2012 instance?

Our application uses v10.0 of the webforms ReportViewer control and typically we connect to one of several 2008 SSRS instances.  However we have had to setup a new secure environment for one of our clients and have deployed our application to it.  We are seeing some strange behavior and I just found out that this new environment runs SQL Server 2012 and therefore SSRS 2012.

The problem we are seeing is that some users of the web application get the following message in the ReportViewer control:

"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

This doesn't seem like a client specific issue since the connection to the SSRS server is made by the application and the rendered output is sent to the client.  Before we go too far into troubleshooting this issue I feel like I need to try and verify whether this combination should work ok, or if there are known incompatibilities.

Unfortunately it's a fairly big effort to just swap out the ReportViewer control we are using to the latest version that aligns with SSRS 2012 and so I'm trying to see if anyone has successfully gotten this to work without issues or not.

Thanks.